# Python Scrapy - Not Getting Any Content For Certain Page

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape some info from offerup.com and on the **scrapy shell**, nothing comes up.

I will type:

`scrapy shell https://offerup.com/`

It will go there but then if I simply try to get text of the whole webpage with:

`response.xpath('//text()').extract()`

it comes back with:

`['Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 623000250007296502-10946686267359632']`

It comes back with nothing for any other info I try to get for the response such as the title.
Do you know why this happens?  Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Please post full lines of code that you are using.

Comment: If you find a way around the 403, please let us know!

Comment: @Naltroc It was actually a very easy work around.  All you need to do is change the user agent to be a normal browser!  Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 1):

Take care to read the response you get when visitng offerup.

> [s] Available Scrapy objects:
>
> [s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains
>   scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
>
> [s]   crawler
>
> [s]   item {}
>
> [s]   request    https://offerup.com>
>
> **[s]   response   <403
>   https://offerup.com>**

You get a 403, a **Forbidden** error. Nothing can bypass a 403.

If you try a different site, such as http://buffalo.craigslist.org, an OK response of 200 is given. Using the same command will show the desired page, and using `response.xpath('//text()').extract()` will print all of the text elements from root.

Some sites may have anti-scraping measures set up to prevent robots from hogging their resources. Offerup is apparently such a site.

To direclty answer your question, your code is functional, but the target site prevents you from using it.